# Limiting behavior of sum of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

I was looking into the following problem and I can not think of a solution.

> Consider i.i.d. random variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, ...$, such that $X_{i}$ has a uniform distribution over the interval $(0, 1)$. Find the following limit:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \leq 2 \sum_{i=1}^n{X_{i}^2}\right).$$

The only thing that occurred to me is evaluate each summand independently when
$$X_i \leq 2 X^{2}_{i}$$ is equivalent to $X_{i}(1-X_{i}) \leq X^2_{i}$, which implies $(1-X_{i} \leq X_{i})$ and the probability of this event is equal to $1/2$. Overall probability would be $(1/2)^{n}$ (since the summands are independent), its limit would be $0$. But that is not the limit I was supposed to look for.

Comment: Yes, but it's not required that *all* the $X_i\geq \frac12$ in order for the inequality to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: divide both sides by $n$.  What does the strong law of large numbers say about each side as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: That the left side converges to the mean of a uniformly distributed r.v. which is $1/2$ and the right side converges to twice the mean of a squared unif. distributed r.v. which is $2/3$ in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't the weak law of large numbers be more applicable here?

Comment: So can I state that since $$P(lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{X^_{n}} - 2\hat{X^{2}}_n = -1/6) =1$$ (convergence almost surely) then the original limit is 1 also?

Comment: Yes, the original limit is $1$ also; you could use the weak law of large numbers too, but that would require a tiny bit more work.  It's basically the same thing.